# Add reputation earned in UNIKONG to total reputation

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, unikong

After spending grueling hours risking my lives fighting monsters in UNIKONG, I expected all the reputation and badges I earned to be added to my account. I was disappointed to discover this is not the case. Did the vast amounts of resources I consumed running headless reputation farming servers all go to waste?

Comment: Yes. ----------

Comment: Sure hope you're trying to continue on the April's fool theme and you aren't serious there...

Comment: Yup. I also realised zero-width whitespaces no longer work.

Comment: To SO community: Award my answers some bounty or I'm going to up-vote this question and start advocating it's validity.

Comment: I knew @Dumbledore was evil all along, but nobody ever believed me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Something like that will indeed happen.  At the end of the day, your SO rep will be added to your UNIKONG score and your SO rep reset to 1.

Comment: Oh thanks for correcting my misunderstanding. I will now convert my servers from phantomjs unikong reputation farming mode to stackoverflow upvote bots mode.

Comment: Note that this is going to happen at the end of UTC day. So please don't ask questions like *My SO rep didn't get reset to 1, is this really going to happen?*

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to allow for daylight-saving time.

Answer (score 13):

> Did the vast amounts of resources I consumed running headless reputation farming servers all go to waste?

Yes. But know that we truly appreciate all the time you spent playing and that you [never gave up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

Comment: Rickroll by bluefeet. Truly only on april 1st a sight to be seen.

Comment: @Magisch you should know that video ID by heart and never click it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a terrible idea, because it would cause all of the people who post crappy answers to duplicate questions just to get rep to stop doing that and start playing the game instead.  As a result, the moderators would have nothing to do and there would be nothing to talk about on meta.  Everyone loses.

Comment: After a week, all the 20K+ repwhores would be on UNIKONG and, once so easily identified, they can all be banned at once:)

Comment: actually... if they stop answering bad questions and expose themselves by playing the game... a)we identify them. b) bad questions stop getting answered.